# Crash when found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value that is not nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, option-type

I'm developing an iOS database app using Firebase. After Authentication (which performs successfully), the userUID gets passed from my LoginViewController to my HomeViewController. Then, in my HomeViewController, I use the user's UID to get the rest of the user's info from the Cloud Firestore associated with that UID. After retrieving it, I want to show the first and last name in a label. I'm certain that the retrieval of the info is successful and that I do have two strings (firstName and lastName). When I print them in the console I get precisely what I want. But I don't know why, when I try to show such strings in a label, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/fafa/Documents/Advisory Program/Advisory Program/HomeViewController.swift, line 41

I've tried several things, but I can't seem to fix this. Here's part of my code:

### **LoginViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let error = validateFields()
    
    if error != nil {
        
        showErrorMessage(error!)
        
    } else {
        
        let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                
                self.showErrorMessage(error!.localizedDescription)
            
            } else {
                
                let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as? HomeViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeViewController!, animated: true)
                
                homeViewController!.userUID = result!.user.uid
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## **HomeViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("teachers").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userUID).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    
        if let error = error {
                    
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
                    
        } else {

            for document in snapshot!.documents {

                // Error gets printed in the following line
                TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView().teacherNameLabel.text = "\(document.get("firstName") ?? "default value") \(document.get("lastName") ?? "default value")" 

                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## **TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView.swift**

```
class TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet weak var teacherHeaderView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var teacherPhoto: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var teacherNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        //teacherHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 140/255, green: 3/255, blue: 3/255, alpha: 1)
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = teacherHeaderView.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        teacherHeaderView.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 0)
        teacherHeaderView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        teacherHeaderView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
        teacherPhoto.layer.cornerRadius =  teacherPhoto.frame.width/2.0
        teacherPhoto.clipsToBounds = true
        teacherNameLabel.textColor = .white
    }

    func configure(image:UIImage, name:String) {
        teacherPhoto.image = image
        teacherNameLabel.text = name
    }

    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: You are making a common mistake: `TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView()` creates always a new instance of the controller which is **not** the instance in the storyboard and therefore the outlets are not connected. And even it was the proper instance it would also crash because the view is not loaded yet. In any case you need the actual instance via segue or instantiation from the storyboard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `teacherNameLabel` of type `UILabel` is `nil`. You have to initialize the `TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView` from xib to avoid the crash. In this line: `TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView().teacherNameLabel.text` you're trying to create a new instance of `TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView` by using an empty initializer. Using an empty initializer would not load the subviews that you've created in the interface builder. Here's an example of how you initialize the `TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView` properly.

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil)
let teacherHeaderCollectionReusableView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? TeacherHeaderCollectionReusableView
teacherHeaderCollectionReusableView?.teacherNameLabel.text = "..."
```